# Android studio error running emulator screen shot provided

Tags: android-studio

Keep getting this error and have tried pretty much everything I have found on this website and no luck.[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI9qe.jpg)

Comment: You might need to activate some BIOS settings,  but first, try to install the HAXM driver from the SDK Tools see https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Answer (score 0):

It means that the hardware acceleration is either disabled or not available for your cpu.

Most intel chips and amd chips have this feature. All AMD Ryzen cpus have this feature. Check the website for your cpu if it is available.

Now if it is disabled then you can go to bios to enable it.

If you are on amd cpu then it won't work with windows os. Windows os can support only intel cpus for hardware acceleration using haxm or recently on Ryzen cpus with windows 10 latest april update and hyper-v enabled.

If you are using amd cpus before the ryzen series, you can switch to any linux distro which will be fine, at it has kvm for hardware acceleration.